# Structuring go interfaces with subpackages

Tags: go, interface, directory, coding-style, directory-structure

I am developing my first real go application and am trying to wrap my hand around my codefiles should be structured.

The main part of my code is going to be a number of types which all implement a common interface.

```golang
type Runner interface {
  Run() string
}
```

They are going to be in a package. As the number of the interface implementations is going to be very large I would like to split them (semantically) into a couple of subpackages.

```
runner/
  blue/
  red/
```

The `Runner` implementation need access to a couple of other interfaces that are defined elsewhere in my application (e.g., `Cache` and `Secret`). Those are currently defined & implemented in separate packages. My plan is to use a `Config` struct, which contains all those utility interfaces and pass it to the `Runner` implementations.

I am unsure how to best handle those subpackages and where to put the `Config` and interface declarations.
My intuitive approach would be to define both the `Config` struct and the `Runner` interface in the `runner` package and only return a `[]Runner` collection from there, but this violates [this recommendation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#interfaces).
Also, the number of imports required and the danger of running into circular references which are prohibited gives me the feeling, that my solution is going against best practices.

Are there any suggestions how to improve my code structure?
Would adding a `common` package which contains all my interface definitions and the `Config` struct be advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a `domain` package containing the interface and `Config` definintions.

So in `domain/domain.go` I have

```golang
package domain


type Config struct {
    Cache
}

type Runner interface {
  Run() string
}

type Cache interface {
  // ...
}
```

The runners are structured in subpackages as mentioned above. I do not export the types but rather have a function in each package collecting all of them and returning it them as interfaces.

`runner/blue/blue.go`:

```golang
package blue

import "my/domain"

func All(config domain.Config) (list []domain.Runner) {
    list = append(list, fooRunner{Config: config})
    list = append(list, barRunner{Config: config})
    return
}
```

`runner/runner.go`:

```golang
package runner

import ( 
  "my/runner/blue"
  "my/runner/red"
  "my/runner/domain"
)

func All(config domain.Config) (list []domain.Runner) {
    list = append(list, blue.All(config)...)
    list = append(list, red.All(config)...)
    return
}
```